# EF Core Driver cannot load netstandard or one of its dependencies in LinqPad 5

Tags: entity-framework, .net-standard, linqpad, ef-core-2.2

I created a .NET Full Framework class library using EF Core v 2.2.1 and downloaded the EF Core driver v 2.x for Linqpad 5 (5.36.03), and when I try to create a new connection to the class library DLL, I get the following error message:

Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependenceis. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have clicked the 'Restore nuGet Dependencies' and it gives me the message 'No NuGet dependencies detected'.

Any thoughts?

Comment: make sure .net sdk/target pack 4.7.2 is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Did exactly what @magicandre1981 suggested and targted 4.7.2 for my class library.  That fixed it!